# Bootstrap modal of image gallary just fading the page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, gallery

I'm trying to build a portfolio Page for my business but having trouble getting the Modal to work. 
The javascript just executes:  without the modal.
Thanks for your help!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a href="#image1" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/test.jpg" alt="alt-text"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="image1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <li><img src="images/test.jpg"/></li>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Schlie&szlig;en</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "The javascript just executes"? Are you sure it does? A common problem is that people forget about adding the bootstrap javascript files into the HTML. Every bootstrap functionality triggered by `data-toggle` needs the javascript files included. If you were thinking about this, please post a minimal working example on jsbin or so.

Comment: Yes im sure that it does. Not Pretty without image & CSS but should work: http://jsbin.com/zexicurita/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing an example on jsbin, this makes it much easier for us to help you.

Your problem lies within the first row of this excerpt:

```
<div id="image1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1"> <!-- here -->
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
```

Bootstrap's `.hide` class is defined like this:

```
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This means that whatever happens, elements with the class `.hide` will stay hidden. This is ensured with the `!important` rule.

To solve your issue, you either remove the `.hide` class from `div#image1` like this:

```
<div id="image1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"> <!-- no hide class -->
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
```

Or you supply an `onclick` listener which removes the `.hide` class if a click occurs. Though, this should not be necessary, since Bootstrap's modal is not visible by default.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Removing .hide solved it. Thank you very much!